# knitr: get parent document filename

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using `knitr` with `rmarkdown` and including a single child document into many `.Rmd` files to render a ToC:

````
```{r, eval = TRUE, child = 'toc.Rmd'}
```
````

What is the canonical way for the `toc.Rmd` file to find out the path of the parent document in which it is being included (so that it can highlight the current entry in the ToC)?

Currently I am using

```
names(knitr::opts_knit$get("encoding"))[1]
```

but that seems to work simply by accident, and I'm wondering whether there is a supported, official way.